# Prolog - compare 2 lists that contain other lists as elements

Tags: list, prolog, equality

I' m new to PROLOG and I find it quite challenging.
I need to return T/F if 2 lists have the same elements (they are equal), regardless their position in the lists.
So far I can easily compare the 2 lists if their elements consists of characters, strings or numbers.
But I can't find out how to compare lists which contains numbers and lists of numbers OR characters and lists of characters.

For example:

```
?- compare([[15,7,5],9,4],[4,[5,15,7],9])
true.
```

But:

```
?- compare([22,[100,36],1],[[36,100],[22,1]])
false.
?- compare([22,[100,36],1],[[[36,100]],22,1])
false.
?- compare([22,100,36,1],[[36,100,22,1]])
false.
```

Any ideas how can i implement such a Program?

Thanks

Comment: Prolog doesn't return `true` or `false`. In fact, it doesn't return anything. A program either succeeds or fails. If it succeeds that you can inspect the variables in your query and see their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list([]) :- !.
list([_|_]) :- !.

reccheck([],[]).
reccheck([H|T],[HH|TT]):-
    recSort(H,HH),
    reccheck(T,TT).

recSort(L,L):-
    \+ list(L).
recSort(In,Out):-
    list(In),
    reccheck(In,SubSortL),
    sort(SubSortL,Out).

compare(L1,L2):-
    recSort(L1,LL),
    recSort(L2,LL).

?- compare([[15,7,5],9,4],[4,[5,15,7],9]).
true ;
false.

?- compare([22,[100,36],1],[[36,100],[22,1]]).
false.

?- compare([22,[100,36],1],[[[36,100]],22,1]).
false.

?- compare([22,100,36,1],[[36,100,22,1]]).
false.
```

So my solution recursively sorts any sublists and compares if the two sorted lists are the same. The recursively sorting needs two predicates. One which sorts (recursive) lists (`recSort/2`) and one which traverses lists and applies the sorting `recSort` to all elements of the list (`reccheck/2`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, you can use flatten.

**1.**  First using is_list to find all the inner list, Then comparing the inner lists using the innerListCheck predicate. flatten simply takes all the inner lists and makes them into one list. flatten both the list, then check that both list have equal length. After that use checkmember predicate.

**2.** The checkmember predicate checks the elements of the first list with the second list. if all the elements of the first list exist in the second then they are same.

```
compare(List1,List2):-
list(List1,A1),
list(List2,A2),
innerListCheck(A1,A2),
flatten(List1,[W1|R1]),
flatten(List2,Res2),
length([W1|R1],Len1),
length(Res2,Len2),
Len1=Len2,
checkmember([W1|R1],Res2).

checkmember([],_).
checkmember([H|T],List2):-
    ( member(H,List2)->
    checkmember(T,List2)).
    
innerListCheck([],[]).
innerListCheck([H|T],[H2|T2]):-
    check2(H,H2),
    innerListCheck(T,T2).

check2([],_).
check2([H|T],[H2|T2]):-
    member(H,[H2|T2]),
    check2(T,[H2|T2]).
    

list([],[]).
list([H|T],[H|B]):-
    is_list(H),
    list(T,B).
list([H|T],B):-
    \+is_list(H),
    list(T,B).
```

**Example:-**

```
?-compare([22,[100,36],1],[[36,100],[22,1],[9]]).
false
?-compare([22,100,36,1],[[36,100,22,1]])
false
?-compare([22,[100,36],1],[[[36,100]],22,1])
false
?-compare([22,100,36,1],[[36,100,22,1]])
false
?-compare([[15,7,5],9,4],[4,[5,15,7],9])
true
false
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  compare([22,[100,36],1],[[36,100],[22,1]]). should be false though. The concept is, if the 2 lists contain sublists that contain the same elements regardless their position, then the output should be true. So I kinda need the 2 lists not only to contain the same elements, but the same sublists too. Like the example i gave. Thanks

Comment: It should be true, First List after flatten becomes: [22,100,36,1] and second [36,100,22,1]. Hence when compared should be true.

Comment: @user14819924 ok that's a different concept. Let me see.

Answer (score 0):

Just a more concise implementation of the recursive sorting predicate, by using `maplist/3`:

```
rsort(A, B) :-
    (  is_list(A)
    -> sort(A, S),           % sort input list
       maplist(rsort, S, B)  % recursively sort each element of the sorted input list
    ;  A = B  ).

compare(A, B) :-
    rsort(A, S),
    rsort(B, S).
```